# unittest - skip folder/do not run tests inside folder automatically

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have two folders with tests in this project:

```
/tests/...
/tests_manual/...
```

I want `unittest` to skip `/tests_manual/...` folder, or, just discover tests in `/tests/...`

Tests inside `/tests_manual/...` should only be run manually this way:

```
python -m unittest tests_manual/test_something.py
```

How can I do that?

I don't want to use `@unittest.skip` decoratos as then `python -m unittest tests_manual/test_something.py` wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Could `python -m unittest discovery -s "/tests/"` be an option?

Comment: @enslaved_programmer Yes that would work but  I'd prefer excluding the /tests_manual/ automatically as I want to be sure nobody runs them without explicitly specifying them.

Comment: Is `pytest` allowed?

Comment: @enslaved_programmer It's not being used here, I don't want to rewrite all the tests. I thought there is some easy way to tell unittest discovery not to take into account a given folder, but if not, `python -m unittest discovery -s "/tests/" ` is also a way to go. Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure that unittest doesn't support folder exclusion and only pytest does. Pytest does support running `unittest` based tests see [link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/unittest.html)